# windows server 2008 r2 blue screen error

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

My server is giving an error like below.

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
HARDWARE MALFUNCTION
CALL YOUR HARDWARE VENDOR FOR SUPPIRT.
NMI:PARITY CHECK MEMORY/PARITY ERROR.
THE SYSTEM HAS HALTED.
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

And we called to hp support team the did check and he checked some logs and he said will not occur this problem.after few days again samething is showing an error.hp team is saying that is not hardware problem and which is software problem and followup microsoft team.

please let me now the solution regarding this problem as soon as possible.

Comment: The solution is to tell HP to stop giving you the runaround and give you the proper replacement parts.

Comment: Alternatively run a [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) test to confirm if your memory is faulty.

Answer (score 0):

In the BIOS setup, go to the Advanced menu, then Bus Options, and disable PCI SERR# Generation option. Save and exit your BIOS settings so that the computer reboots again.